# getting data from website to android studio?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm practicing how to import data from website into an app. After much googling i realize easiest way was to use `Jsoup` Library. I looked through tutorials but i couldn't get how would i get news from `http://www.theguardian.com/us` . 
The following is the main news path from google developers tools.

```
#eu-referendum > div > div.fc-container--rolled-up-hide.fc-container__body.fc-show-more--hidden > div:nth-child(1)
```

this is what i figured out with Jsoup but do not know how to select a class or even get div:nth-child(1)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://http://www.theguardian.com/us/").get();
Element mast = doc.select();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs it looks like you should do:

> Element mast = doc.select("#eu-referendum > div > div.fc-container__body > div:nth-child(1)");

and if you find out what your selector returns than open chrome developer tools and in the console type: $("put here your selector") and see what it returns.